Using verb and verbatim in tabular or tabularray
My question
I would like to include code blocks in tables. So far, I have been able to include code blocks in my normal text using the verbatim command.
I have four files, of which only file 1 compiles correctly. How can I fix the other files? What are alternatives to verbatim which provide the same ease-of-use?




verb
verbatim




tabular
✅ File 1
❌ File 2


tabularray
❌ File 3
❌ File 4



File 1 (verb + tabular)
Input:
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Test & Test & Test \\
Test & \verb|Test| & Test \\
Test & Test & Test \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Output:

File 2 (verbatim + tabular)
Input:
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Test & Test & Test \\
Test &
\begin{verbatim}
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
\end{verbatim}
& Test \\
Test & Test & Test \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Error:
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.8 \begin{verbatim}
                    
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.8 \begin{verbatim}

File 3 (verb + tabularray)
Input:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]},rowspec={Q[m]Q[m]Q[m]}}
Test & Test & Test \\
Test & \verb|Test| & Test \\
Test & Test & Test \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

Error:
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.11 \end
         {tblr}
? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.11 \end
         {tblr}

File 4 (verbatim + tabularray)
Input:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]},rowspec={Q[m]Q[m]Q[m]}}
Test & Test & Test \\
Test &
\begin{verbatim}
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
\end{verbatim}
& Test \\
Test & Test & Test \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

Error:
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.17 \end
         {tblr}
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.17 \end
         {tblr}


Solution
The solution is to use the verbatimbox package
Fixed file 2 (verbatim + tabular)
Input:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbbox}
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
\end{verbbox}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Test & Test & Test \\
Test & \theverbbox & Test \\
Test & Test & Test \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Output:

Fixed file 3 (verb + tabularray)
Input:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbbox}
Test
\end{verbbox}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]},rowspec={Q[m]Q[m]Q[m]}}
Test & Test & Test \\
Test & \theverbbox & Test \\
Test & Test & Test \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

Output:

Fixed file 4 (verbatim + tabularray)
Input:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbbox}
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
\end{verbbox}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]},rowspec={Q[m]Q[m]Q[m]}}
Test & Test & Test \\
Test & \theverbbox & Test \\
Test & Test & Test \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

Output:

